# Jenkins boolean parameter is always true in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, boolean

I have a Jenkins job that calls a groovy script and the groovy script uses Jenkins parameters to do it's work. I can retrieve all the parameters without a problem except for a boolean parameter. The boolean parameter is a checkbox in Jenkins

[image: unselected boolean parameter]

I read the jenkins parameter into Groovy as follows:

```
boolean libraryBranch = config.get('library_branch_feature');
```

Now when I print the 'libraryBranch' variable

```
out.println "-- Library branch feature?: " + libraryBranch.toString();
```

I get the following printed line:

> -- Library branch feature ?: true

So it doesn't matter if the boolean Jenkins parameter is selected or not I always have a boolean value 'true' in Groovy. All other (string) parameters inside the same job are read without a problem.

Can someone help me with this issue?

**EDIT**

Ok I've decided to try and retrieve the code in a couple of other ways and tyring to find a good solution:

```
Boolean libraryBranch = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("library_branch_feature");
String libraryBranchString = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("library_branch_feature").toString();
Boolean libraryBranchStringAsBoolean = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("library_branch_feature") as Boolean;
```

The above variables are then printed:

```
out.println "-- Library branch feature?: " + libraryBranch;
out.println "-- Library branch feature to String: " + libraryBranch.toString();
out.println "-- Library branch feature to String: " + libraryBranch.toString();
out.println "-- Library branch feature as String: " + libraryBranchString;
out.println "-- Library branch feature String as Boolean: " + libraryBranchStringAsBoolean;
```

The output of the above prints are posted below:

```
-- Library branch feature?: true
-- Library branch feature to String: true
-- Library branch feature to String: true
-- Library branch feature as String: false
-- Library branch feature String as Boolean: true
```

So the only way thus far to have the boolean value read correctly as a false is by not turning it into a boolean at all but just reading it as a string and use it as a string.

I would rather use it as a boolean though so any suggestions on the matter is still appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is to read the Jenkins parameter as String and then convert it to a boolean using the method .toBoolean(); So my libraryBranch is now set as follows:

```
boolean libraryBranch = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("library_branch_feature").toString().toBoolean();
```

Comment: What? Why is that?

Answer (score 12):

The question and the answers are a bit dated. The modern method to
consume a boolean parameter is to use the `params.` global values. **params**
properly exposes Boolean parameters such that the following both work and
require no string/boolean conversions.

```
            if (params.library_branch_feature) {
                // truth logic here
            }
// or 
            if (params.library_branch_feature != false) {
                // truth logic here
            }
```

From the **Pipeline Syntax** for **params.**:

Exposes all parameters defined in the build as a read-only map with variously typed values. Example:

if (params.BOOLEAN_PARAM_NAME) {doSomething()}
or to supply a nontrivial default value:

if (params.getOrDefault('BOOLEAN_PARAM_NAME', true)) {doSomething()}

NOTE:
It may not make sense that a boolean parameter can have NO value,
but '.getOrDefault()' is useful to set default values for string parameters.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, except false logic. It should be `if(!params.library_branch_feature) { // false logic here }`

Comment: does this always work sometimes I get it ok sometimes jenkins still goes crazy and skips my stages when it feels like

Answer (score 10):

Just out of curiosity, I tried the following:

Set the variable 'testmode' as a boolean in the pipeline setup.
Start the job, with testmode set false (unchecked).
In the pipeline script, run the following code immediately upon entry:

```
    testmode=testmode.toBoolean()
    if (testmode==false) { print "testmode tests true"}else{print "testmode tests false"}
```

you will see the result 'testmode tests false'.

To verify my claim that the 'boolean' variable testmode is ACTUALLY a string when it comes in, I tried:

```
    testmode=testmode.toBoolean()
    testmode=testmode.toBoolean()
```

and it blew up on the 2nd 'toBoolean'.  I'll spare you the error message...

So, I claim that testmode comes in as the string "false" instead of as a boolean (whether because of promotion, demotion, forcing, whatever).

So, if its a boolean parameter, and you really wanted to treat it like a boolean and not have to say 'if (booleanvar=="true")', then convert it to a boolean as above and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with reading java Properties - retrieved boolean values are always true. So, say I have a `settings` file with property `debugging=false`. This test will fail:

```
class ConfigurationTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testProcessConfiguration() {
        Properties properties=new Properties()
        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader('settings')
        properties.load(fileReader)
        boolean debug=properties.getOrDefault('debugging',false)
        assert !debug
        fileReader.close()
    }
}
```

But if you make it `properties.getOrDefault('debugging',false).toString().toBoolean()` it will return correct value. Probably this is because of coercion?